# Outlook can not recognize newer PDF version (like v1.7+) being attached to an email and treats it badly as plain text

Tags: linux, microsoft-outlook, pdf, thunderbird, file-corruption

When attaching PDF v1.7 to an email in Outlook, it's sent as:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

When receiving such an e-mail under Linux (Thunderbird), the PDF content is being parsed as a plain text and converted. This results in a corrupted file loosing all the bytes 0x0d (CR) which are being removed by the EOL conversion.

On the contrast, when attaching an older PDF (like v1.3) to an email in Outlook, it's sent correctly as:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

which is received and decoded correctly.

It's definitely a problem of Outlook (all versions up to 2013 - latest available in the time of writing).

I'm not the creator nor the sender of those attachments! Our company is just suffering from that issue while receiving hundreds of PDFs each day sent by people from outside. We can not force all the senders to place the PDFs in an archive or to fix it on their side.

I want to ask if somebody has been facing this and if there is a way how to force Thunderbird to bypass the plain-text EOL conversion when Content-Type is "application/pdf", or something like that to workaround the problem on the ***receiver*** side.

Comment: Why don't you increase the PDF version being used?  You could just place the file in an archive.

Comment: Definitely, but I'm the receiver, not the sender. So things become more complicated when we talk about hundreds of employees receiving hundreds of corrupted pdfs a day. Negotiation and resending in an archive is not the solution for that case.

Comment: "Why don't you increase the PDF version being used?" - v1.7 is the current ISO-approved version. Any [later extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Adobe.27s_versions) by [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) are not part of the reference spec. v2.0 is still under development by the ISO.

Comment: I updated the question, hope it is more explanatory now. Thanks

Comment: The same faced today, `X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 15.0`, saving attachments on Thunderbird 31.2.0 (x84-64, Linux)